# Assembly: Difference between add instruction and operator add

Tags: assembly

Is there any difference between the following two:

```
mov     eax, [eax+4]
```

and

```
add     eax, 4
mov     eax, [eax]
```

If not then, does the assembler choose which one to pick for some kind of optimization?

Comment: Beware the negative number !

Answer (score 4):

There are a few differences between these two pieces of code. For one, the instruction encoding and sizes. The first is encoded as follows...

```
8b 40 04                mov    eax, [eax+4]
```

...amounting two 3 bytes.

For the second one...

```
83 c0 04                add    eax, 4
8b 00                   mov    eax, [eax]
```

...totals 5 bytes.

Moreover, the add instruction sets the `OF` (overflow), `SF` (sign), `ZF` (zero), `AF` (adjust/auxiliary), `CF` (carry), and `PF` (parity) flags according to the result. The `mov` instruction neither sets or scrambles any of these flags.

Finally to answer your last question... No. There is no existing assembler that helps with any optimization. Code in assembly is compiled on a strictly literal basis. My suggestion is to use the 3-byte piece of code, as it is shorter and executes faster.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes,if we don´t need a flag of the flagregister and if the result of an address-calculation with an addition of two register and/or with a multiplication by 2, 4 and 8 for a scaling, and also together with a replacement value, if the result of this represents a valid address inside of the address-space, then we can use the this address calculation within brackets for a code optimisation. Specially the LEA-instruction is very usefull in this case, if we only need a simple integer calculation, but no memory access. Example: "lea eax,[eax+1]" for replacing and instead of an "inc eax"-instruction.

Comment: Technically, `lea eax, [eax+1]` is less space-efficient than the `inc eax` instruction, but I think you get the idea. To clarify to other people,  `lea` becomes most useful when requiring a `mov` and `add` instruction for a different register consecutively such as `lea eax, [ebx+1]` taking up less space than `add ebx, 1` and `mov eax, ebx` combined. However, in the case of adding 1, `inc eax` is the most efficient of them all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are differences. Whether you care about them is a different matter. The `add` affects the flags, the `[eax+4]` doesn't. The two versions have different instruction and byte counts and they possibly use different execution units. These might matter when optimizing.

Normally, the assembler will not change your code, whatever you write is what you will get.